# How to make a dictionary from a file?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have the following file (tab delimited):

```
ID  Name    Abbr    Disctrict
*data*
1   Newcastle   NC  AA,BB,CC
2   Manchester  MCR AA,DD,FF
3   Liverpool   LV  FF,GG,HH
```

Im trying to place `index[1]` as key and `index[3]` as values inside a dictionary. It doesnt seem to work yet.

```
my_dict = {}

path = (r'c:\data\GG\Desktop\Extra\UK_test_cities.txt')

with open(path, 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        (key, val) = line.split()
        my_dict[int(key)] = val
```

**This is my output:**

```
  File "c:/data/GG/Desktop/Extra/test_1.py", line 17, in <module>
    (key, val) = line.split()
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

**This is my desired output:**

```
my_dict = {'Newcastle': ['AA,BB,CC'],
           'Manchester': ['AA,DD,FF'],
           'Liverpool': ['FF,GG,HH']}
```

Comment: is it tab-delimited or single space delimited?

Comment: @buran tab delimited

Comment: The "line.split()" produces your "index" list from which you have to extract the desired items like you showed in your description.

Comment: note that values in your desired output is single element list, not list with each district being separate element

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there is 4 column in each line

```py
from collections import defaultdict 

path = (r'c:\data\GG\Desktop\Extra\UK_test_cities.txt')
my_dict=defaultdict()

with open(path, 'r') as f:
    content = f.readlines()
for line in content[2:]: #First two line does not contain data
    _,key,_,val = line.split()
    my_dict[key] = val
```

Comment: Parjbar can you explain where you using index[1] and [3] in your code?

Comment: ``` _,key,_,val = line.split() ```
in this line you extract position 1 as key and 3 as value and ignore the rest.

Comment: So what if I had more positions after the 3th one?Lets say I have 5 positions

Comment: you should change the code as below:
fields = line.split()
key,val=fields[1],fields[3]

Comment: what is fields? Can you show it in your code please?

Comment: fields is just a variable assigned by line.split()
change _,key,_,val = line.split() line to fields = line.split() key,val=fields[1],fields[3]

Comment: There is really no need to use `defaultdict`.

Answer (score 1):

```
my_dict = {}
path = r'c:\data\GG\Desktop\Extra\UK_test_cities.txt'
with open(path, 'r') as f:
    for _ in range(2): # skip first 2 lines
        next(f)
    for line in f:
        idx, name, abbr, district = line.split('\t')
        my_dict[name] = district.strip().split(',')

print(my_dict)
```

Alternatively, you can use csv module or pandas.

```
import pandas as pd
path = r'c:\data\GG\Desktop\Extra\UK_test_cities.txt'
df = pd.read_csv(path, sep='\t', skiprows=2, index_col='Name',
                 usecols=[1, 3], names=['Name', 'District'])
df['District'] = df['District'].str.split(',')
my_dict = df.T.to_dict('index')['District']
print(my_dict)
print(my_dict)
```

Both snippets will produce

```
{'Newcastle': ['AA', 'BB', 'CC'], 'Manchester': ['AA', 'DD', 'FF'], 'Liverpool': ['FF', 'GG', 'HH']}
```

Comment: `idx, name, abbr, district = line.split('\t')
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 4, got 1)`

Comment: So, you don't test with tab-delimited file or have have blank lines? In any case there is line without tab. Or do you really have a line `*data*` in your file?

Comment: my tab delimited file looks 100% exactly the same as in my question.So yes with `*data*` With you snippet I keep receiving the following error: `idx, name, abbr, district = line.split('\t')
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 4, got 1)`